Möbius strip is a smooth submanifold
I want to find a description of the Möbius strip without boundary as a submanifold.
To be more specific, what I mean with "description". I know the following proposition:
For a subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ the following are equivalent:

$M$ is a ($k$-dim)submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$
For all $x \in M$, there exists a subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x \in U$ and a smooth function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that
i) $M \cap U=f^{-1}({0})$
ii) for all $y \in M \cap U$, the map $DF(y): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is surjective.
For all $x \in M$, there exist open subsets $V \subseteq M$ with $x \in V$ and $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ and a smooth function $g:W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that
i) $g$ is a homeomorphism $W \rightarrow V$
ii) for every $y \in W$, $D g(y):\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is injective.

So if one wants to show that the Möbius strip without boundary is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ one could either try to show it by using the definition of a submanifold or try to show that the möbius strip statisfies either 2. or 3. of the proposition mentioned above. I want to know how one can show that the Möbius strip without boundary is a submanifold by either using 2. or 3. (ideally both, but for getting started one should be enough).
Sidenote: I am new to differential geometry and manifolds, so I do not have a lot of experience. If there are other/better ways to find a description of a Möbius strip without boundary, please tell me (as far as they are on a "beginner level").
Thanks in advance for any help.

What have you tried?

@BenSteffan I have tried to do Nr.2, but I do not really know how to start.

For a start, you should probably write down what subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ you consider as the Möbius strip.

You could see it as a sub manifold of the filled torus, which would be
$$X = \left\{\left( \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{2}\cos \beta \right)\cos \alpha, \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{2}\cos \beta \right)\sin \alpha, \frac{\lambda}{2}\sin \beta \right), \alpha,\beta \in ]-\pi,\pi] ,\, 0\leq \lambda \leq 1\right\}$$
Basically for every point of the circle $\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1, \, z= 0\}$ you add a normal disk of radius $1/2$, so you have a good diffeomorphism with $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{D}^2$ and we have $\partial X = T \cong \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 $.
It can be seen as a twisted cyclic ribbon, with half a turn, so we set
$$\gamma_0(\theta) = \left( \left(1+\frac{\cos \theta/2}{2} \right)\cos \theta, \left(1+\frac{\cos \theta/2}{2} \right)\sin \theta, \frac{\sin \theta/2}{2} \right)$$
$$\gamma_1(\theta) = \left( \left(1+\frac{\cos (\pi + \theta/2)}{2} \right)\cos \theta, \left(1+\frac{\cos (\pi + \theta/2)}{2} \right)\sin \theta, \frac{\sin (\pi + \theta/2)}{2} \right)$$
Basically they live on the torus (so the boundary of $X$) and when $\gamma_0$ is at one point of the normal circle, $\gamma_1$ is at the other end.
You can easily see that $\gamma_0(\theta + 2\pi) = \gamma_1(\theta + 2 \pi)$ and $\gamma_0(\theta + 4 \pi) = \gamma_0(\theta)$.
Now we consider our Möbius strip
$$Y = \bigsqcup_{\theta \in ]-\pi,\pi]} ]\gamma_0(\theta),\gamma_1(\theta)[ = \left\{ (1-t)\gamma_0(\theta) + t\gamma_1(\theta), \theta \in ]-\pi,\pi], \, 0<t<1 \right\}.$$
One can exhibit our homeomorphism from the Möbius strip $M = [0,1]\times ]0,1[ /\sim$ where $(0,t) \sim (1,1-t)$ by applying the quotient theorem to the surjection:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
[0,1] \times ]0,1[ & \to & Y \\
(s,t) & \mapsto & (1-t)\gamma_0(2\pi t) + t\gamma_1(2\pi t)
\end{array}$$
Indeed the only non-trivial fibers are the $\{(0,t),(1,1-t)\}$ so applying our quotient theorem, we have the homeomorphism $M \cong Y$. I did not prove it was a diffeomorphism, but I let you dot it :)
If you prefer one definition of the Möbius strip as a quotient of $\mathbb{R} \times ]0,1[$, the same map (extended) will do the job.
